# YouTube keeps lowering the automatic quality even with very good internet speed

Tags: video, youtube

If I leave the quality of a video on "automatic", on a long video it will start at the highest, and every few minutes it will knock it down one step, until I'm seeing the video in in the lowest (144p).

If I set manually the quality to 1080p, for instance, it works fine on any video of any length.

My internet speed is good, so I don't think that's the problem.

[image]

Does anyone know what could be the reason for this? Is it something to do with my Wifi?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 2ms ping is a really suspicious SpeedTest result. Try again, dialling in a distant server manually [You will need the web version not the app to do this easily, as you can search]. Pick something the other side of a large ocean. …or use http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest instead. They're less biased than ST. If you can still get good solid figures, then next is to look at your router's QoS settings.

Comment: Hi, using dslreports.com/speedtest I get ~800 mbps download, and setting SpeedTest to the other side of the world I get 143 ping and 284 mbps download. In any case, the speed is good, as when I select the quality manually I never have problems loading the videos.

Could you explain to someone that doesn't know much about this what should I look regarding my router's QoS settings, please?